# Why is the grease pencil on this specific area didn't render like the rest of the outlines?

Tags: rendering, grease-pencil

Why is the grease pencil on the bottles area didn't render like the rest of the outlines? For additional info, those lines that didn't render properly were drawn while in front view while the rest is with the camera view toggled on.

This is the rendered image.
[image]

This is the viewport rendered image.
[image]

Here are the settings when I was working on this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the labels separate GP object or a separate layer in a GP object? Check Strokes > Stroke Depth Order in the Grease Pencil Data properties.

Comment: yes, it's separated. the stroke depth order is in 2D layers. Tried it in 3D location but it got worse lol. I just went with having it exported through viewport render image. Is it the same? Anyways, thanks for answering!

Comment: I didn't see any difference in the quality of the renders, so that is a good and fast workaround. It is a good idea, if you can, to share a portion of the scene file with the problematic area. That may help immensely in finding the solution.

Comment: Is this what you're referring to? https://imgur.com/a/Qq6ZI6e
Sorry I'm still pretty new in Blender.